# Will AWS Mobile SDK libraries go away due to Amplify?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-sdk-ios, aws-amplify-sdk-android

Currently, the company I work for uses AWS libraries in multiple Android apps, AWS libraries like:

```
com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3
com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client
com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools
com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-core
```

When I try to look up documentation for these libraries, I can only find Xamarin docs. Android and iOS documentation is missing, and I see ominous warnings that "On October 30, 2021, AWS Amplify will replace AWS Mobile Hub"

What's not clear is if "AWS Mobile Hub" just consists of the online Mobile Hub interface, or if it includes these libraries I've been using.

Will I be able to use the AWS SDK libraries indefinitely, or will they stop functioning on October 30, 2021? I haven't been able to find anything that directly answers this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are *three* terms that I'll aim to disambiguate, here.

Firstly, the `aws-android-sdk-*` libraries you've referenced are collectively referred to as the **AWS Mobile SDK for Android**. You can find documentation for "the SDK," [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/q/platform/android). This software is used for direct interaction with our various AWS services.

**AWS Mobile Hub** was a web-based resource-management interface. It is distinct from the SDK artifacts that you've mentioned, above. A few of the AWS pages ([example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/Reference.html)) include a deprecation note like this:

> On October 30, 2021, AWS Amplify will replace AWS Mobile Hub. For more information, see Migrating to Amplify.

The [**Amplify Android Library**](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/q/platform/android) is AWS' current and recommended tool for accessing AWS resources from Android. Amplify is a high-level wrapper around the AWS Mobile SDK for Android. Unlike the mobile SDK, which provides a *breadth* of functionality, Amplify is focused on getting common tasks done easily.

> Will I be able to use the AWS SDK libraries indefinitely

We recommend you evaluate migration to the Amplify libraries. The AWS Mobile SDK will continue be maintained with bug fixes and security updates.

> Will they stop functioning on October 30, 2021?

No. The AWS Mobile SDK for Android will continue to function past this date.

Source: I am a senior engineer employed by AWS' mobile team.